# Again with JSON deserialize and IOS (ObjectiveC)

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I've this string returning from a JSON deserialization:

```
extradata: [
      {
        "tourDetails" : {
          "idTour" : 5113123132407808,
          "id" : 5730082031140864,
          "externalNotes" : "nullissimo",
          "name" : "Essential London",
          "description" : "This two-hour walking tour will take you past a great many of London's most important sights as well as along part of the ceremonial route that the Queen followed on her Diamond Jubilee in June 2012. It also leads you past the sites of two events of the glorious 2012 Olympic Games.  The idea of the Essential London Walk is to give you a taster of what is what and where it is. Return later at your leisure to such `icons' as Westminster Abbey, the Houses of Parliament or the London Eye for your own up close and personal visit and inspection. Essential London Walk is the key to learning the fascinating and often surprising background stories to Europe's premier city. This walking tour takes in the most important landmarks in London, including Parliament, Westminster Abbey, Trafalgar Square, Downing Street, Horse Guards Parade, the London Eye, the River Thames and Buckingham Palace.",
          "idLang" : 5629499534213120
        },
        "tour" : {
          "internalNotes" : "no notesssss",
          "id" : 5113123132407808,
          "code" : "BASE-ESS",
          "photoPath" : "http:\/\/cdn.londonandpartners.com\/asset\/c3291aa543a4ae6f15640dd087d8febb.jpg",
          "lon" : -0.1338786,
          "duration" : 2,
          "managedBy" : "omg",
          "type" : 1,
          "place" : "Piccadilly Circus",
          "lat" : 51.5102583,
          "calendarDuration" : 1
        }
      },
      {
        "tourDetails" : {
          "idTour" : 5118084088070144,
          "id" : 5656058538229760,
          "externalNotes" : "prova x vedere una pic",
          "name" : "Amy Winehouse's Camden",
          "description" : "Wander around Camden, following the trail of Amy and her pals",
          "idLang" : 5629499534213120
        },
        "tour" : {
          "internalNotes" : "no notesssss",
          "id" : 5118084088070144,
          "code" : "BASE-",
          "photoPath" : "http:\/\/www.ohmyguidelondon.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/07\/Dollarphotoclub_21556157.jpg",
          "lon" : -0.133878600000002,
          "duration" : 2,
          "managedBy" : "omg",
          "type" : 1,
          "place" : "Piccadilly Circus",
          "lat" : 51.5102583,
          "calendarDuration" : 1
        }
      },
      {
        "tourDetails" : {
          "idTour" : 5659313586569216,
          "id" : 5634472569470976,
          "externalNotes" : "NOTEPROVA",
          "name" : "Covent Garden Tour",
          "description" : "DESCRIZIONEPROVA",
          "idLang" : 5629499534213120
        },
        "tour" : {
          "internalNotes" : "CODICE PROVA",
          "id" : 5659313586569216,
          "code" : "codprova",
          "photoPath" : "http:\/\/www.ohmyguidelondon.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/07\/Dollarphotoclub_3313745.jpg",
          "lon" : -0.1232697000000371,
          "duration" : 2.5,
          "type" : 1,
          "place" : "Covent Garden",
          "lat" : 51.5117321,
          "calendarDuration" : 1
        }
      },
      {
        "tourDetails" : {
          "idTour" : 6270652252160000,
          "id" : 5684666375864320,
          "externalNotes" : "",
          "name" : "British museum guided tour",
          "description" : "This walk will take you through the streets of the village of Hampstead with the unique selection of little bars, restaurants and furniture, books and antique shops, and some of the amazing houses and villas owned by film and TV celebrities.\r\n \r\nThen we will make our way and walk through the iconic Heath, one of the largest and popular open spaces in London, with landscape with a series of meadows, woodlands.  On the way we will be seeing the famous 5 ponds, open to the public and included the one for men, women or mixed (bring a towel if you wish to dip in- , experience the wild life (with a touch of luck meet the local squirrels, wild rabbit, foxes, and few others). \r\n \r\nThe great view from Parliament Hill Fields and finishing with the visit of one of the most exclusive ancient mansion right up to the top of the heath, the Kenwood House, the site of the Kenwood summer concert.\r\n \r\nAfter we will be visiting the famous pub \"The Spaniard Inn\" (1585) a favourite stop of the highwaymen but also favourite of Dickens, Joshua Reynolds and Brian Stocker, before heading to London.\r\n \r\nEste tour es tambien disponible en Castellano!\r\n \r\nQuesta passeggiata e' disponibile anche in Italiano\r\n \r\nThe tours starts from Hampstead Tube Station and ends in Archway ( there is a bus ride from the Heath to the tube station)",
          "idLang" : 5629499534213120
        },
        "tour" : {
          "internalNotes" : "Prova British",
          "id" : 6270652252160000,
          "code" : "British museum guided tour",
          "photoPath" : "http:\/\/www.ohmyguidelondon.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/07\/Dollarphotoclub_86907.jpg",
          "lon" : -0.08584700000000001,
          "duration" : 2,
          "managedBy" : "omg",
          "type" : 1,
          "place" : "British Museum",
          "lat" : 51.510191,
          "calendarDuration" : 1
        }
      }
]
```

I understood that is an array with Dictionaries inside. So I've tried to retrieve data in this way:

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *retData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSDictionary *dic = [retData objectForKey:@"extraData"];
```

Until here, it's all ok!!!

But I still haven't found a method to retrieve the single data: tourDetails, tour ect...

Someone can help me? Tks.

Answer (score 2):

This is incorrect:

```
NSDictionary *dic = [retData objectForKey:@"extraData"];
```

as `extradata` (**not** `extraData`) is an array, according to the JSON you posted:

```
NSArray *arr = retData[@"extradata"];
```

and each dictionary can be enumerated using *fast enumeration*:

```
for (NSDictionary *innerDict in arr) {
    NSDictionary *tourDetails = innerDict[@"tourDetails"];
    NSLog(@"tourDetails=%@", tourDetails);
}
```

However by the look of your comment, you are receiving a string object, not an array object.  That doesn't match your JSON, but perhaps it's returned in the case of error from the server.  You can cope with both situations using:

```
id topObject = retData[@"extradata"];
if ([topObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    NSArray *arr = (NSArray *)topObject;
    // Success; proceed as above
} else {
    NSLog(@"Failed to retrieve JSON data: %@", topObject);
}
```

Comment: No sir... don't works!!!
This is the error I get on "for" instruction:
[__NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]

Comment: Oh... and I know that is case sensitive... this (extradata (not extraData) ) was a refuse! But thanks a lot for your response....

Comment: @Blasco73 Updated my answer with possible solution to your issue.

Comment: Yes you are right..... The returning class is an NSString. I've tried with your code and with [NSDictionary class] too but ever fail.
Works only with [NSString class].
Sorry can this depends from the server code? Because I suppose that the call is correct....

Comment: Yes.  What's in the string?

Comment: You can check it on my question: all data except: "extradata:" 
the string starts with [{"tour":{"id":5113123132407808,"code":"BASE-ESS","type":1,"place":"Piccadilly  ect...

Comment: @Blasco73 OK, I think you are looking at a server-side error (it's not correctly encoding the response) or something is missing in your code that you have not shown.  What you have shown should have worked perfectly well; i.e. you are able to access the top-level dictionary without error, so it's valid JSON up to that point.

Comment: Yes I know... I'm using the same code with other projects and works perfectly.... I will try to control the server side code.
Thank you very much....

Answer (score 0):

*extradata* is `NSArray` which contains `NSDictionaries`.

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *retData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSArray *array = (NSArray*)[retData objectForKey:@"extraData"];
```

Now for example, you want to get the tourDetails or tour which is present at first index.

```
NSDictionary *dic = [array objectAtIndex:1];
NSDictionary *tourDetailsDic = dic objectForKey:@"tourDetails"];
NSDictionary * tourDic = dic objectForKey:@"tour"];
```

Comment: than you for your response... but still don't works. I retrieve the same error!!! in this line: NSDictionary *dic = [array objectAtIndex:1]; with the same reason of above: -[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]

Comment: Are you getting string or array from json! It seems like it is of string type.

Comment: Yes you got my problem... after this: NSArray *array = (NSArray*)[retData objectForKey:@"extraData"]; I retrieve a string....
I've to parse it manually....

Answer (score 0):

You can go deeply in your `NSDictionary` through others `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` related to the `json file`:

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *retData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSArray *globalArray = [retData objectForKey:@"extradata"];
for(int i = 0; i < [globalArray count]; i++) {
    NSDictionary *toDisplay = [globalArray objectAtIndex:i];

    // Here is how you retrieve your "tour" and "tourDetails" datas
    NSDictionary *tourDetails = [toDisplay objectForKey:@"tourDetails"];
    NSDictionary *tour = [toDisplay objectForKey:@"tour"];
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"tour: %@\ntourDetails: %@", tour, tourDetails]);
}
```

Comment: You do know that `NSLog()` already supports formatting, without the use of `[NSString stringWithFormat:]`?

Comment: @trojanfoe, I do know, but this is a old habit, thank you for reminder

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. I'm found the problem and the solution:
The Problem: the data returned from server was full of "" symbols. So it cannot read as a structure but simply as a string.
The solution: the solution was a double deserialization:

```
NSDictionary *retData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSString *retStr = [retData objectForKey:@"extraData"];
NSData *newData = [retStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:newData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

only after this operations I can access to the "real" structure:

```
NSDictionary *newDict = [json objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *test = [[newDict objectForKey:@"tour"] objectForKey:@"id"];
```